# Почему данные не записываются в файл json?

Tags: c#, json, wpf

При нажатии на кнопку у меня должна происходить запись в файл, но ничего не происходит

Вот код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("user.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
         {
              Class1 tom = new Class1("Tom", "37");
              await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<Class1>(fs, tom);   
         }
    }
}
```

Код класса:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(string name, string age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    string Name { get; set; }
    string Age { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `string Name { get; set; }` => `public string Name { get; set; }`

Comment: Гений! Спасибо чел.